# Android get HTML source from web site after login

Tags: android, html, google-chrome

I'm building an Android app where HTML source code is needed from a web page where the user is already logged in. However the app does not know the user/password to login to the web site.
Therefore I first expect the user to login to the website (using Chrome for instance) and then the app could get the source code.

I tried 2 mechanisms but it doesn't work (see below). After several other attempts I decided to post this problem.

Solution 1: New intent to access HTML source code from Chrome :

```
try {
    String url = "googlechrome://navigate?url=" + "view-source:http://www......";
    Intent i = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
    i.setData(Uri.parse(url));
    startActivity(i);
} catch (ActivityNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get the requested source code displayed in Chrome (i.e. no more in my app) but then I'm stuck, I can not capture and send back automatically the code source in the app.

Solution 2 : Standard HTTP connection setup putting the correct browser user agent used by my device :

```
        url = new URL("http://www...........");
        connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.4.2; SM-G800F Build/KOT49H) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/47.0.2526.83 Mobile Safari/537.36");
        connection.setConnectTimeout(10000);
        connection.setReadTimeout(10000);

        sb = new StringBuffer();
        is = new BufferedInputStream(connection.getInputStream());
        br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));
        while ((inputLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(inputLine);
        };
        String htmlString = sb.toString();
```

The app gets the page source but before login (i.e. being already logged in to the web site in Chrome does not help).

Many thanks for your help.